# @font-face Two parse errors

Tags: css, font-face

The site runs perfectly on the desktop browser.

On a mobile phone browser, the site does not read the font files.

So I checked the CSS validator and found 2 errors, parse errors. I've tried a couple different things and can't seem to get rid of the parse errors. Here's the code that is faulty with the errors. The font file is stored locally.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'trashhand';
  src: url('TrashHand.ttf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a fallback system for the font-family usage. For example:

```
font-family:'Trashhand', 'Lucida Sans', 'Arial'
```

The main purpose for fallback system is to create alternative font usage, so if the browser doesn't support the first font it will try the next options.

Comment: The problem that it is reverting to my 1st fallback choice on Chrome for Android, Georgia. I have not checked other mobile devices yet. The CSS is also receiving 2 parse errors in the html validator. 'font-family:trashhand, georgia, sans-serif;' is the current CSS for elements using the font.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import font in proper ways.

CSS TO IMPORT FONT:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'TrashHand';
  src: url('TrashHand.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

CSS USAGE:

```
body{
    font-family:'TrashHand', sans-serif;
}
```

Also, you can see [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) many possiblities to import different fontface for different browser and systems.

Comment: I'll try using a single font family. Right now the elements that use the font have the CSS:  'font-family:trashhand, georgia, sans-serif;' I'll also correct the lowercase 't' and 'h' in the font-family. Thank you. I'll see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, although the `format` hint is optional if your font is `OpenType` or `TrueType`, it's worth specifying it explicitly:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'trashhand';
  src: url('TrashHand.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Besides that, there were some problems with path recognizing on mobile devices. So you can include a `/` to the beginning of your font path and that might fix everything.

The last but not the least, consider using `woff` or `woff2` that are compatible with major browsers.

Comment: I have svg, woff, woff2, and the original ttf files now. I'll fix the format for each of them. I am assuming that it is okay to utilize multiple font formats. Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: @kab Yeah, it's possible and even recommended to use multiple font formats. Please read [the following article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/).